# Not able to check if file exists on S3(Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.169.254:80)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, paperclip, aws-fargate

We are using `paperclip` gem to use S3 functionality(upload, fetch, check if file present).

We are not providing AWS keys in code, we are using role-based mechanism.

Things work fine on ECS-EC2 but break on ECS fargate but both have the same role and the same attach policies.

On fargate we are getting

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.169.254:80 (Invalid argument - connect(2) for "169.254.169.254" port 80)
```

Any ideas?.

Comment: That is the EC2 metadata endpoint URL. Fargate has a different metadata endpoint URL. It looks like the library you are using doesn't have support for running on Fargate unfortunately.

Comment: Note that Paperclip is deprecated, and hasn't been updated in years. They recommend using Rails Active Storage instead: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html